# C++ How do I implement this one parameter constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

In this project, I have to create a class called Chain. A chain will be a list of values (like an array). The thing is I have to create this chain without the use of the STL library.

Right now, I have to implement this one parameter constructor:

```
Chain(const Object& item)
{
    // Write something.
}
```

"Object" by the way is just the name of the template for the class.

I have these two private variables as part of the class:

```
size_t size_;
Object *array_;
```

Let's say I wanted to make this call from main:

```
Chain<int> d{7};
```

That's just saying pass 7 to the one parameter constructor.

How would I go about implementing this one parameter constructor?

Also, I need to be able to print out this class if from main I type for example:

```
Chain<int> d{7};  // A chain containing 7 should be created.
cout << d;  // Should just print [7]
```

In order to do that, I have to implement this overloaded << operator:

```
// Overloading the << operator.
 friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Chain &a_chain)
 {
   // Print the chain.
   return out;
 }
```

Attempted code so far:

```
// One parameter constructor.

Chain(const Object& item)
{

array_ = new Object[item];
// array_=item;
size_++;
}

// Overloading the << operator.
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Chain &a_chain)
{

   cout << array_ << endl;

   return out;
}
```

Comment: You can't use a literal when the constructor expects a reference. A reference needs to refer to a variable.

Comment: All that boldface is pretty annoying. Not to mention distracting.

Comment: @Barmar: what? http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Yhx9q3HtkkEay4Ee

Comment: Yeah a `const` reference can take a literal argument.

Comment: Barmar, so that's the constructor I was given for the project. Maybe the call is wrong. So, how would you call it and how would you implement it?

Comment: I forgot about the `const` distinction.

Comment: @Dan "without the use of the STL library."

Comment: What is the 1-parameter constructor supposed to do? Create a 1-element array containing the value of the parameter?

Comment: @Dan I think it's clear that the object of this exercise is to to implement your own vector-like class. Why don't people understand pedagogy, and think people are trying to implement real applications when they post questions here with constraints like this?

Comment: @Dan That's like a carpentry school starting by teaching how to put together Ikea furniture.

Comment: @Dan How do you know they didn't already teach that? We have to address this exercise on its own terms.

Comment: Yes @Barmar the one parameter constructor is supposed to add 7 to this class. So then if I print out the object, it should cout "7".

Comment: I think I need to do something with the *array_ member variable. Because I think that's how I add this 7 to this class

Comment: So what problem are you having? Use `new Object` to allocate memory for the array, and copy `item` into it.

Comment: Actually, it should be `new Object[1]`, because the destructor will assume that `array_` points to an array, not a single object.

Comment: @Barmar, like this? 
 // One parameter constructor.
  Chain(const Object& item)
  {

    array_ = new Object(item);
    size_++;
  }

Answer (score 1):

With these types of things, it's best to take things one step at a time, making sure you've got each small piece working before adding additional complexity.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more details.

For the code (now) you've shown, here is code that does **exactly** what you've described, and **nothing** more.

```
template<typename T>
struct Chain
{
    T value;
};

// Overloading the << operator.
template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Chain<T> &a_chain)
{
    out << a_chain.value << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Chain<int> d{ 7 };  // A chain containing 7 should be created.
    std::cout << d;  // Should just print [7]

    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `Object* array_` isn't necessary to get this snippet of code working.  Once you're satisfied with what this does, you can add more pieces.  For example, if you really are trying to implement your own `std::vector<>`-like class (bad idea), your next step might be to *remove* templates as that's an additional complexity.

Comment: True, I didn't mention that I don't think I'm allowed to add new members to the class. The reason why I was dealing with *array_ is because I think that's where I add the members.

Like if I added 7 and then 2 and then 10 to an object of the class, and then I print it out, it should print out `7 2 10`